# How to enable skipNegotiation setting in Blazor Server

Tags: blazor-server-side

How to enable skipNegotiation setting in Blazor Server for avoid sticky sessions

In documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/signalr/scale?view=aspnetcore-5.0

> When all clients are configured to only use WebSockets, and the
> SkipNegotiation setting is enabled in the client configuration

Answer (score 4):

In _Host.cshtml

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js" autostart="false"></script>
<script>
    Blazor.start({
        configureSignalR: function (builder) {
            builder.withUrl("/_blazor", {
                skipNegotiation: true,
                transport: 1
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this along with the following in `Startup.cs`: `endpoints.MapBlazorHub(options => options.Transports = HttpTransportType.WebSockets);` However, I receive WebSocket connection failed errors, "There was an error with the transport". Is there something I'm missing? Did you add `MapBlazorHub` config changes in your `Startup.cs` as well?

Comment: You saved my day!! I was having the same issue, and this solution solved that. Thank you.